# Belgium visa but travelling to Italy

Tags: visas, schengen, belgium

I have a multiple entry Belgium Schengen tourist visa for 30 days, however my travel plans have changed.. can I now goto Italy on the same visa or shall I apply for a fresh Schengen visa for Italy.. what are the pros and cons of travelling to Italy on a Belgium Schengen visa?
Regards,
Tushar